# How Can I Set Default Code to Chrome Console?

Tags: google-chrome-console

I use chrome console with specific code pieces. For every tab or different window I should write the code again. Is there any way to set a code pices that will work every opening new tab and window?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run snippets of javaScript on any page with Chrome DevTools [snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets).

Comment: thank for the link. I use snippets. My code is saved. But I should run the code every time. Is it possible to time run one times the snippet

Comment: Then use this google chrome feature - 
[live expressions](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/live-expressions)